# Best method to get permanent network mount directly to my home folder

Tags: macos, mount, smb

I'm using macOS Big Sur.

I read a couple of methods of mounting network drives:

1. Command line: `mount_smbfs //user@server/folder /Users/me/localfolder`
   The problem with this one is the mount point will be gone after restarting (not permanent). If I have to run the script at login, it will ask password on every login. I don't want to put/expose my password on the script like `//user:pass@server/folder`
   Any solution?
2. Add login items (via System Preferences > User > Login Items).
   The problem with this method is that it will mount it automatically on `/Volumes/` then I have to add another script to make a symlink from this `/Volumes/xxx` to my `/Users/me/localfolder`. I prefer to mount directly to the home directory.

Any other method?

EDIT, for more details I add this real scenario:

I'm doing a project with a team (every user use their own workstation/laptop). The 'project root' or 'working folder' can be in any folder as long as it's inside the home dir, for example:

```
/Users/andi/Desktop/__rootfolder__
/Users/John/Documents/projects/__rootfolder__
/Users/Sam/Projects/__rootfolder__
or anywhere else as long as inside /Users/<username>/
```

Now to be able to pass projects to each other and not getting broken links. I set up a 'virtual root folder' or symlink which are the same for all users. So every user then has to link their `whatever_user_root` to  `/Volumes/\_\_rootfolder__`. For example:

```
sudo ln -s /Users/andi/Desktop/__rootfolder__ /Volumes/
```

Now inside the app we use, the working folder is `/Volumes/\_\_rootfolder__` which is the same for all users so the app doesn't know and doesn't care about `/Users/blabla`... . So when we send a project to another user, the symlink will sort it out for you.

Additionally, there's an **asset** folder (contains library, reference, etc) which will be shared with all users located on server -> `//192.168.1.10/assets`. This will be mounted inside `__rootfolder__` of each user.

For example it will appear in :

```
/Users/andi/Desktop/__rootfolder__/assets
/Users/John/Documents/projects/__rootfolder__/assets
etc
```

So I do :

```
mount_smbfs //user@192.168.1.10/assets /Users/andi/Desktop/__rootfolder__/assets
```

Inside the virtual folder it will look:  `/Volumes/\_\_rootfolder__/assets` <-- This will be the same for all users regardless of where their working folder is.

This is why I prefer `mount_smbfs` to mount 'assets' directly to the user folder. Because when using login items, I have to mount to `/volumes/` then do symlink back to user dir.

To recap:

1. Create user working directory or root folder inside each user folder.
2. Make a symlink in `/Volumes/rootfolder` to point to `user_rootfolder`.
3. Mount `//server/assets` to `/Volumes/assets`.
4. Make symlink `/Volumes/assets` to `user_rootfolder/assets`.
5. Any user works will be contained inside `user_rootfolder` or `/Volumes/rootfolder`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to mount it to a subdirectory of your home folder?

Comment: Why not use a symlink to link /Volumes/ServerName to /Users/you/ServerNameFolder? Symlinks work in terminal and in Finder? Do you have an issue like this person: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/141833/406217 (this doesn’t have your answer, just has a problem that I’m wondering if you have).

Comment: @MarcWilson, Pls check my post. i've just added lot detail about my plan, explaining why i need to link back to user dir etc. If you see better workflow , pls let me know.

Comment: @anonymous, pls check my post, i edit it to explain the real problem.

Comment: The symlink in the user folder needs to be created only once. Also, `sudo ln -s /Users/andi/Desktop/__rootfolder__ /Volumes/` doesn't actually do this (arguments should be the other way around), and doesn't require `sudo` if done correctly.

Comment: @nohillside sorry what do you mean the argument is wrong ? ln -s <source> <link>, i think you misunderstood the plan. I want to mount from /user to /volumes not the other way around. It need sudo.

Comment: I may not understand what you want to accomplish then. In which directory do you mount, in which directory do you create the symlink?

Comment: Also, `/Volumes` is primarily managed by macOS. Creating symlinks manually there is at least cumbersome (as you've noticed). Can't you just mount the SMB drive there and then either set up global symlinks in `/Users/Shared` or (IMHO better) set up the correct structures with symlinks in each user directory?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the Users folder? As it can be anywhere in there why can't it be anywhere else? There is nothing special about that folder .  (Having spent much of my Unix work time in folders outside my $HOME directory).

Comment: @mmmmmm just my preferable. if has multiple users in 1 pc/mac, easier to maintain. Rather than have to setup another folder and manage privileges . Why don't just use existing $HOME. The app i use (Nuke) use $home in their private environment, when i need to pass the preference file of the app among other users , i don't have to worry about it or no need to change it for every users.